# How to implement partials from ejs in vuejs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Can someone explain me please about the views in the nodejs?

I am building a shop online. I will list an example about my question:
I want to setup a get a single or multiple product and to create a ejs partial with those dates from the database. So in my views i create a ejs files, with css and everything for the functionality.
How can i send to frontend the response when i will make a call with axios?
Is my approach wrong or i miss something?
I am new with mvc. Please dont be cruel. Thanks